# Angular2 Ngrx effects services load and hit twice my service

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I try to play with  Ngrx effects services, but it seems like it hit twice my request

My dispatch

```
this.store.dispatch(new workspacesActions.LoadWorkspaceDetailsActions(this.id));
```

Effect service:

```
export class loadDetailsWorkspaceEffectSservice {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private WkService: WorkspacesService) {

    }

    @Effect() detailsWorkspace$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(ActionTypes.LOADWOKSPACESINFOS)
        .switchMap(arg =>

            this.WkService.getDetails(arg.payload))
        .map((workspace) => new workspacesActions.FetchWorkspaceDetailsActions(workspace) );
}
```

My service

```
 @Injectable()
export class WorkspacesService {  
public _getDetails;

        public getDetails(id: number) { 
        this.spinner.show()
        this._getDetails = this.http.get(config.apiWorkspacesDetailsURL + id, this.jwt())
            .share()
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() =>  this.spinner.hide());

        return this._getDetails;
    }
}
```

My Actions

```
export class LoadWorkspaceDetailsActions implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.LOADWOKSPACESINFOS;
    constructor(public payload?: any) { }
}

export class FetchWorkspaceDetailsActions implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.FETCHWOKSPACESINFOS;

   constructor(public payload?: any) { }


}
```

My reducer

```
...
//////////////////
    case WorkspacesActions.ActionTypes.LOADWOKSPACESINFOS:
      return state;

    //////////////////
    case WorkspacesActions.ActionTypes.FETCHWOKSPACESINFOS:
      const resultWS = action.payload;

      return Object.assign(state, {
          workspaceDetails: resultWS.workspace
        });
...
```

I end up with two http request and 2 responses !

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add WkService.getDetails function and action ts file ?

Comment: @ThienHoang thanks just added

Comment: this looks usual. are you sure you are not dispatching an action twice? can you share part of the code that dispatches action?

Comment: it seems like I dispatch it just one by using :

this.store.dispatch(new workspacesActions.LoadWorkspaceDetailsActions(this.id));

Comment: Did you try use effect before with other action ? And is it normal (1 times)

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/61 I met this stuff in this case, you can refer it

Comment: First time I m using effect and It seems like I had the same behavior for all my actions. 
When I check Redux devTools, it seems like The actions is dispatched twice !

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to archieve by returning a local variable and using the share operator?

Comment: @LintonB same as `Module A import EffectsModule.run(AEffects),
Module B import EffectsModule.run(BEffects), and Module A`. So it is called twice

Comment: I was using the share operator because I read it will prevent to call twice if the observable was defined. But it doesn t seems to work I probably gonna remove it. I actually follow this tuto https://medium.com/@flashMasterJim/the-basics-of-ngrx-effects-effect-and-async-middleware-for-ngrx-store-in-angular-2-f25587493329

I think the issue is that I declare the effect in a sharedModule that I'm using everywhere (Thien Hoang github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/61)

Comment: So in case you import effect in modules , please make sure you import it in AppModule ( main module ). I think this is bug of ngrx/effect

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks Everyone :) and thanks @ThienHoang 
As I said I was running my effect in my shared module, and as I use it in different places it cause multiple calls.

Thanks

Comment: No problem, good to hear that  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try ExhaustMap instead SwitchMap:

```
@Effect() 
detailsWorkspace$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.LOADWOKSPACESINFOS),
    exhaustMap(arg => this.WkService.getDetails(arg.payload)),
    map(workspace => new workspacesActions.FetchWorkspaceDetailsActions(workspace))
)
```

or with new syntax (ngrx 8)

```
detailsWorkspace$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.LOADWOKSPACESINFOS),
    exhaustMap(arg => this.WkService.getDetails(arg.payload)),
    map(workspace => new workspacesActions.FetchWorkspaceDetailsActions(workspace))
);
```

exhaustMap prevents sending new requests untill previous completed
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html